# How can I put condition on Controller index function that if the button is On this conditions should not work, and if button off condition should work

Tags: laravel, controller

I have created a checkbox in the setting page from the database it works fine, ON and OFF works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTfE1.png)

Now i want if it is off this condition should work, and if on it should not work.

```
public function index() 
{
    if (permission::permitted('dashboard')=='fail'){ return redirect()->route('denied'); }







// Updated Code of Auto Clockout Start


**$clockedInUsers = DB::table('people_attendance')
    ->whereNull('timeout')
    ->get();

foreach ($clockedInUsers as $user) {
    $timeIn = Carbon::parse($user->timein);
    $currentTime = Carbon::now();

    // Get the first clock-in time of the day for the user
    $firstClockIn = DB::table('people_attendance')
        ->where('employee', $user->employee)
        ->where('date', $timeIn->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->orderBy('timein')
        ->first();

    if (!$firstClockIn) {
        continue; // Skip users with no clock-ins for the day
    }

    $firstClockInTime = Carbon::parse($firstClockIn->timein);
    $clockInCount = DB::table('people_attendance')
        ->where('employee', $user->employee)
        ->where('date', $timeIn->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->count();

    // Define different auto-clockout times and totalhours based on the clock-in count
    $autoClockOutIntervals = [
        1 => ['minutes' => 330, 'totalhours' => '5.30'],
        2 => ['minutes' => 720, 'totalhours' => '12'],
        3 => ['minutes' => 720, 'totalhours' => '12'],
    ];

    if (isset($autoClockOutIntervals[$clockInCount])) {
        $intervalData = $autoClockOutIntervals[$clockInCount];
        $autoClockOutMinutes = $intervalData['minutes'];
        $autoClockOutTime = $firstClockInTime->copy()->addMinutes($autoClockOutMinutes);

        if ($currentTime >= $autoClockOutTime) {
            $newTimeout = $firstClockInTime->addMinutes($autoClockOutMinutes)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            DB::table('people_attendance')
                ->where('id', $user->id)
                ->update([
                    'timeout' => $newTimeout,
                    'totalhours' => $intervalData['totalhours']
                ]);
        }
    }
}
```

// Updated Code of Auto Clockout End**

I dont know what should i do exactly to put a condition over there. on the index function.

Comment: We also don't know what is your issue , which lines of code didn't work !

Answer (score 0):

If a checkbox was not checked when you submit a form the checkbox value won’t be sended in the request. You can use an if condition like this:

```
if(isset($request->input(‘checkbox’))){
  // code
} else{
  // code
}
```